# Change multiple cell values based on single cell value

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataframe:

```
a = c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no")
b = c("brown", "grey", "white", "grey", NA)
c = c(7, 6, NA, 10, 8)
d = c("male", "female", "female", "male", "female")
Zoo = cbind.data.frame(a, b, c, d)
colnames(Zoo) = c("animal", "colour", "age", "gender")    

   animal colour  age  gender
    yes    brown   7   male
    yes    grey    6 female
    no     white  NA female
    yes    grey   10   male
    no     NA      8 female
```

If the value for 'animal' is no, I would like to change any non-NA values in the corresponding columns to "NL" (for non-logical). I can do this one column at a time as follows:

```
Zoo$colour = as.character(Zoo$colour)

Zoo$colour = 
  ifelse(Zoo$animal == "no" & !is.na(Zoo$colour), "NL", Zoo$colour)
```

and eventually arrive at this:

```
   animal colour  age  gender
    yes    brown   7   male
    yes    grey    6 female
    no     NL     NA     NL
    yes    grey   10   male
    no     NA     NL     NL
```

I'm sure there is a way of doing this more efficiently. Is there? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way. Notice that I create a data.frame with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` because working with factor levels in this setting is tedious. You can freely convert character columns to factors once you're done with this.

Basically, this code goes through each row, finds columns which have non-NAs and inserts `"NL"` in their place.

```
a = c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no")
b = c("brown", "grey", "white", "grey", NA)
c = c(7, 6, NA, 10, 8)
d = c("male", "female", "female", "male", "female")
zoo <- data.frame(animal = a, color = b, age = c, gender = d, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for (i in 1:nrow(zoo)) {
  if (zoo[i, "animal"] == "no") {
    find.el <- !is.na(zoo[i, which(colnames(zoo) != "animal")])
    zoo[, 2:ncol(zoo)][i, find.el] <- "NL"
  }
}

  animal color  age gender
1    yes brown    7   male
2    yes  grey    6 female
3     no    NL <NA>     NL
4    yes  grey   10   male
5     no  <NA>   NL     NL
```

Comment: Works perfectly - I just needed to change the first 'Zoo' in the loop to lower case z.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple columns, we can use the efficient approach with `set` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Zoo)
for(nm in names(Zoo)[-1]) {
  set(Zoo, i = NULL, j = nm, as.character(Zoo[[nm]]))
  set(Zoo, i = which(Zoo[['animal']]=='no' & !is.na(Zoo[[nm]])),
      j = nm, value = "NL")
}

Zoo
#   animal colour age gender
#1:    yes  brown   7   male
#2:    yes   grey   6 female
#3:     no     NL  NA     NL
#4:    yes   grey  10   male
#5:     no     NA  NL     NL
```

NOTE: This should be very efficient as we are using `set`

---

Or otherwise, we can use the elegant `tidyverse` syntax

```
library(dplyr)
Zoo %>% 
   mutate_at(2:4, funs(replace(., Zoo[['animal']]== 'no' & !is.na(.), 'NL')))
#   animal colour  age gender
#1    yes  brown    7   male
#2    yes   grey    6 female
#3     no     NL <NA>     NL
#4    yes   grey   10   male
#5     no   <NA>   NL     NL
```

#### Benchmarks

```
Zoo1 <- Zoo[rep(1:nrow(Zoo), 1e5),]
Zoo2 <- copy(Zoo1)
Zoo3 <- copy(Zoo2)

system.time({
setDT(Zoo2)
for(nm in names(Zoo2)[-1]) {
  set(Zoo2, i = NULL, j = nm, as.character(Zoo2[[nm]]))
  set(Zoo2, i = which(Zoo[['animal']]=='no' & !is.na(Zoo2[[nm]])),
      j = nm, value = "NL")
}
})
# user  system elapsed 
#   0.40    0.01    0.42 

system.time({
  Zoo3 %>% 
   mutate_at(2:4, funs(replace(., Zoo3[['animal']]== 'no' & !is.na(.), 'NL')))
 })
 #user  system elapsed 
 #  0.42    0.03    0.46 


system.time({
 for (i in 1:nrow(Zoo1)) {
  if (Zoo1[i, "animal"] == "no") {
    find.el <- !is.na(Zoo1[i, which(colnames(Zoo1) != "animal")])
    Zoo1[, 2:ncol(Zoo1)][i, find.el] <- "NL"
  }
}
})
#     user  system elapsed 
#  2086.49  577.51 2686.83
```

#### data

```
Zoo <- data.frame(animal = a, colour = b, age = c, gender = d, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Rereading the question I think OP is really after how to apply this logic to all the non-animal columns.

Comment: Yes, that is what I would like to do

Comment: Yes, even the numeric columns should be set to NL if they correspond to a 'no' in the animal column and they are not NA.

Comment: Oh damn, we create the same data.frame. :) I really do need to push refresh more often.

Comment: If your comment is directed at me, I was merely making an observation of convergence about data.frames. It was not meant negative in any shape or form.